# Table td fixed size in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td  valign="top" align="right" style="height:10px;vertical-align:center;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                    <div><img width="25" height="16" src="images/hide.jpg" id="hide"></div>
                </td>   
                <td rowspan="2" valign="top">
                 <iframe src="dynamic.html" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="1100" height="500"></iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                <iframe src="navigation.html" id="leftFrame" name="leftFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width="200" height="500"></iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

first  works in every browser as expected but in **IE**
while opening any document in mainFrame it gets streched as show below

[image]

when i open any document in mainfram it strech the row like

[image]

how to get rid of this..